# Permission denied in Makemkv

Tags: permissions, external-hdd, plex

I'm trying to get plex working on Ubuntu and when I use Makemkv to get the files off my disk, I get the error 'Posix error - Permission denied'.  I am trying to put these files on a bigger external hard drive.

Comment: Could we see the commands you used? Also use write code inside ` like you would do with " for quotes. `If you do you will print code with this format :) `

Comment: this error is coming from makemkv itself not the terminal.

Comment: Hmm maybe you would have more luck in [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) forum then ...